# Passing class' member address correctly with the ability of invoking it

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm struggling with passing member's address to another function.
Here's what im trying to do:

I've the following defention:

```
bool MyClass::FunctionName();
```

and then somewhere in my program i execute the following command:

```
::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NULL, (WPARAM)this, (LPARAM)&MyFunction);
```

where **this** stands for MyClass

Once my WndProc is executed, i try this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::WndProc(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ UINT uMsg, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    Myclass* pClass= (Myclass*)wParam;

    std::function<bool()> pFunc = std::bind(bool(&Myclass::MyFunction)&lParam, pClass);
    pFunc();
}
```

Errors im receving:

> warning C4554: '&' : check operator precedence for possible error; use
>   parentheses to clarify precedence
>
> Error 3   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1
>   arguments c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap  58

Comment: Do not do that! Expecting a WPARAM of a window procedure to be a class pointer will end in disaster (note other may invoke SendMessage, too)

Comment: @DieterLücking, the following WndProc function is being subclassed, i know for sure my class' lifetime is assured to exist.

Comment: The type is called `bool MyClass::*()` and you don't want the *address* of `lParam`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, can you share an example of how it should have been? and what do you mean i dont need the address of lParam?

Comment: You need to cast the *value* of `lParam`, not a pointer to it. `lParam` is a parameter, and its address isn't very useful.

Comment: @DieterLücking What is wrong with using a WPARAM to hold an object pointer?  Yes, others can call SendMessage - don't do that then.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Or did you mean "don't assume that WPARAM is a class pointer regardless of the Windows message"?  In which case, I very much agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this should compile:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::WndProc(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ UINT uMsg, 
                                  _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch (uMsg)
     {
         case WM_METHOD_CALL:
             Myclass* pClass= static_cast<Myclass*>(wParam);

             typedef bool Myclass::pmf();
             const auto pointer_to_member_function = static_cast<pmf>(lParam);
             (pClass->*pointer_to_member_function)();
             break;
     }
}
```

Your problem is that while it is perfectly safe to expect a WPARAM to be a class pointer, a "pointer to member function" is a surprisingly complex beast (consider a virtual function in a second base class), and is typically larger than a single pointer - so it won't fit in an LPARAM.

Given you want to use `SendMessage`, you can do the following:

Move the typedef into Myclass:

```
     typedef bool Myclass::pmf();  // Inside the definition of Myclass.
```

Somewhere in your program:

```
Myclass::pmf ptr = &MyFunction;
::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_METHOD_CALL, (WPARAM)this, (LPARAM)&ptr);
```

Then in your message handler:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::WndProc(_In_ HWND hWnd, _In_ UINT uMsg, 
                                  _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
     Myclass* pClass= static_cast<Myclass*>(wParam);
     switch(uMsg)
     {
         case WM_METHOD_CALL:
             do_method_call(wParam, lParam);
             break;
     }
     return 0; // Or whatever.
}


void do_method_call(_In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
     const auto pointer_to_member_function = *static_cast<Myclass::pmf*>(lParam);
     (pClass->*pointer_to_member_function)();
}
```

Comment: The code needs to switch on message ID. The window will receive messages for which the cast you use in the question is invalid and will fail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Strewth, yes!  (You can tell how long it is since I wrote production windows, code).